# Remove all files associated with a repository, keeping other files

Tags: git, git-rm

I have cloned a "dotfiles" Git repository into my home directory and I'm trying to remove all the files associated with it.

How can I safely remove all files that belong to the repository without accidentally deleting any other files from my home directory?

Comment: How did you clone? Git usually creates a sub-directory for a cloned repo. You cn just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git ls-files` to list the repository files and to pipe the output to `rm`

```
git ls-files | awk -F "/" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | xargs rm -rf
```

After that delete the `.git` folder

```
rm -rf .git
```